# How to use -v to see a list of the files searched for in Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have some Haskell code below.

```hs
-- | Determine the prime factors of a given positive integer.

module P36 where
import Data.List
import Data.Numbers (primeFactors)

prime_factors_mult :: Integer -> [(Integer, Int)]
prime_factors_mult = map encode . group . primeFactors
    where encode xs = (head xs, length xs)
```

I run it in ghci, it gives me the output:

```
Prelude> :l P36
[1 of 1] Compiling P36              ( P36.hs, interpreted )

P36.hs:5:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Numbers’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I know it's because I don't have `Data.Numbers` installed. I have solved it by running `stack install Numbers`.

But I can't figure out what does **Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.** mean.

I Google a lot and I have tried using `:l P36 -v` and `stack -v`. But none of those executed right.

My question is **How to use -v to see a list of the files searched for.**

----- **Update** ------

After running `ghc -v` in console, it shows

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ghc -v
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 8.6.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 8.4.3
Using binary package database: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\sta
ck\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.6.3\lib\package.conf.d\package.cache
package flags []
loading package database C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86
_64-windows\ghc-8.6.3\lib\package.conf.d
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.5.3
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-1.0.2.0
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.12.0.0
wired-in package rts mapped to rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.14.0.0
wired-in package ghc mapped to ghc-8.6.3
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting:
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting:
ghc: no input files
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
```

But I have seen a post [Error: “Failed to load interface for 'Data.Either.Utils'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998196/error-failed-to-load-interface-for-data-either-utils)
 which got a result of running with -v. It's

```
Using a sandbox located at
/Users/myuser/Desktop/mydirectory/myotherdirectory/.cabal-sandbox
/usr/local/bin/ghc --print-global-package-db
/usr/local/bin/runghc filename.hs
```

I check the path `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86
_64-windows\ghc-8.6.3\lib\package.conf.d` and find it has many `.conf` files.

```
C:.
    array-0.5.3.0.conf
    base-4.12.0.0.conf
    binary-0.8.6.0.conf
    bytestring-0.10.8.2.conf
    Cabal-2.4.0.1.conf
    containers-0.6.0.1.conf
    deepseq-1.4.4.0.conf
    directory-1.3.3.0.conf
    .....
```

Are these the files searched by Haskell?

Is my output with `ghc -v` reasonable?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for stack?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I didn't think of this, cause Google doesn't give me any related links. I will look for it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you started GHCi with `stack ghci`, you can pass the `-v` option with `stack ghci --ghc-options -v`.

Stack passes GHC a list of folders where stack installs packages, and where GHC should therefore look for Haskell modules.  So to get useful output from GHC, it's usually necessary to invoke it through `stack`, as above.  The situation is analogous for `cabal` and other build tools.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to call it from the prelude. It is actually a command for the compiler itself, so if you open your terminal/console try to run `ghc -v`. (I assumed you're using GHC as you tagged your question [haskell-stack](/questions/tagged/haskell-stack).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But after running `ghc -v`, the output seems quite different from what I want. I edited the question, could you please take a look at it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, does maybe `cabal` or `ghc-pkg` produce what you want?

Comment: There seems not cabal command on my machine.  `ghc-pkg list` outputs the files in `\package.conf.d` which I have listed in my update.